# Plot very different length of timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm struggling to find optimal settings for plotting time-series that can wildly differ in their length.  To give you more context, the input data are generated by FIO, so they come in microseconds on the "time" axis and all kinds of other measurements on the "value" axis (eg. IOPS, bandwidth, completion latency, submission latency etc.)

The problem: the test generating the data may run for an hour, or for ten minutes, or for ten hours.  That aside, IOPS data-points are much sparser than submission latency (you cannot really measure something-per-second more often than once per second, but submission latency is, typically, within 1-2 microseconds).

When I don't alter `xticks`, the scale on the X (time) axis is usually worthless (i.e. it's either too sparse, or too dense).  For each individual case I can find a "good enough" value for `xticks`, but I cannot think of a way to figure this out automatically.

Here're some of my exercises, sorry, it's slightly out of context, but should at least illustrate the direction I tried.

```
def plot_one(self, args):
    file_name, file, plot_histogram = args
    logging.info('plotting: {}'.format(file_name))
    if type(file) is bytes:
        file = BytesIO(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, usecols=(0, 1))
    df.columns = ['offset', 'nsec']
    df = df.groupby(['offset']).mean()
    df['offset'] = df.index
    if plot_histogram:
        ax = df['nsec'].plot.hist(title=os.path.basename(file_name))
        figure = ax.get_figure()
        figure.savefig(file_name + '_hist.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    max_offset = df['offset'].iloc[-1]
    ratio = max(1, min(max_offset // 4000, 40))
    height = 5
    width = int(height * ratio)
    xticks, step = None, None
    if max_offset > 10000:
        xticks = pd.Series(data=range(0, max_offset // 1000)) * 1000
        step = 1000
    else:
        xticks = pd.Series(data=range(0, max_offset))
        step = 1
    ax = df.plot(
        title=os.path.basename(file_name),
        x='offset',
        y='nsec',
        grid=True,
        figsize=(width, height),
        xticks=xticks,
        rot=90,
    )
    ax.set_xticklabels(xticks // step)
    ax.set_xlim(0, df['offset'].iloc[-1])
    figure = ax.get_figure()
    figure.savefig(file_name + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    logging.info('saving figure: {}.png'.format(file_name))
```

Comment: Note: you can make fio run for a fixed amount of time through the use of [`time_based=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-time-based) and [`runtime=<time>`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-runtime) options...

Comment: Additionally, why are your IOPS results sparser than your latency results? How are you having fio record these results for you? There seem to be lots of things that might affect period over in the [Measurements and reporting section of the fio help](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#measurements-and-reporting)...

Comment: @Anon yes, but it's not what I need. I need it to run for the amount of time that I need it to run. FIO records these results using `write_{lat|bw|iops}_log` setting.

Comment: Doesn't `log_avg_msec` control the period some of these things are averaged over?

Comment: @Anon maybe it does, but this is really not relevant... what's relevant is that sometimes I'll have 100 datapoints, sometimes 10000, and sometimes 10000000. Please, don't try to second-guess me, I know how to run FIO, this is not my problem.

Comment: "Please, don't try to second-guess me" - as you wish.